# Representation of differentiation operator

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

So I have to find a basis for a polynomial space such that differentiation operator is in Jordan form. I noticed that if I chose a basis to be ${1,x^2,x^3,x^4,...,x^n}$ then the differentiation operator is 
$$\begin{matrix}
0&1&0&0&\dots&0
\\0&0&2&0&\dots&0
\\0&0&0&3&\dots&0
\\\vdots&&&&\ddots
\\0&0&0&0&\dots &n
\\0&0&0&0&\dots&0
\end{matrix}$$
This is Jordanish but not Jordan... I wanted to try with a basis where instead of vector $x^n$ I have $\frac{1}{n} x^n$  but of course it does not work. What is the trick here?

Update:
That was quick but I think I found it $\{n!,n!x,\frac{n!}{2!}x^2,\dots,\frac{n!}{(n-1)!}x^{n-1},n!x^n\}$ does the job.

Comment: Neither is it a square matrix.

Comment: @amd please,clarify what you mean

Comment: The matrix that you’ve got in your question has dimension $(n+1)\times n$. It makes no sense to speak of its Jordan normal form. You need a row of zeros at the bottom.

Comment: Have you figured out what the Jordan normal form of the differentiation operator is? That might be a good starting point. You’re on the right track with the basis that you’re trying, at any rate.

Comment: @amd now I got what you meant I will updeate the matrix. I found the basis I think. And do you mean that I should know the normal form since the matrix Ihave have characteristic polynomial $\lambda^n=0$ what implies the only eigenvalue is 0?

Comment: That’s not enough to determine the JNF. You also need to know either the minimal polynomial or the dimension of the eigenspace of $0$.

Comment: You’ve got a stray factor of $n$ in the last basis vector. That aside, why clutter things up with the common factor of $n!$? The set $\{x^k/k!\}$ works just as well and the coefficient has a transparent relationship to $D^k(x^k)$. In any case, if you’ve solved your own problem, you should write it up as an answer to this question.